# Keep alive sticky

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need help to make code which can keep alive sticky (and they content), and when key ESC will be pressed, only one, active sticky will be closed. How to define OpenWindow? Use MySql or cookies for keep alive?

Actualy code: https://jsfiddle.net/venntr/14fs0fef/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  function limitTextareaLine(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && $(this).val().split("\n").length >= $(this).attr('rows')) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  $(function() {
    $('textarea.limited').keydown(limitTextareaLine);
  });
  var x = "<div class='darkYellow'><span class='close ui-icon ui-icon-close'></span>Sticky<div class='lightYellow'><textarea maxlength='250' rows='8' cols='25' class='limited'></textarea></div></div>";
  $('#click').click(function() {
    $('#one').append('<div class="note">' + x + '</div>');
    $(".darkYellow").draggable();
    $('.close').each(function() {
      $('.close').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
      });
    });
  });
  $('.darkYellow').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass("index");
  });
  $('.darkYellow').on('blur', function() {
    $(this).removeClass("index");
  });
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
      window.open(location, '_self', '');
      openedWindow.close();
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: Very broad - many ways. I'd imagine some unique id creation and persistence scheme. Perhaps esc key deletes the last one created? Simple demo/starting point: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mapbeL6r/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes to your code that may be helpful to achieve your target:

```
var arr = [];
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function limitTextareaLine(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13 && $(this).val().split("\n").length >= $(this).attr('rows')) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        $(function() {
            $('textarea.limited').keydown(limitTextareaLine);
        });
        var x = "<div class='darkYellow'><span class='close ui-icon ui-icon-close' onclick='closeIt($(this));'></span>Sticky<div class='lightYellow'><textarea maxlength='250' rows='8' cols='25' class='limited'></textarea></div></div>";
        $('#click').click(function() {
            var count = $('.note').length + 1;
            $('.note').removeClass('active');
            $('#one').append('<div class="note '+count+' active">' + x + '</div>');
            arr.push(count);
            $(".darkYellow").draggable();
        });     
        $('body').click(function(e) {
            var target = $(e.target);
            if (target.parents('.note').length > 0) {
                $('.note').removeClass('active');
                target.parents('.note').addClass('active');
            }
            console.log(arr);
        });
        $(document).keyup(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                if ($('.note').length > 0) {
                    if ($('.note.active').length > 0) {
                        var cls = parseInt($('.note.active').attr('class').split(' ')[1]);
                        var index = arr.indexOf(cls);
                        console.log('.note.active.'+cls+' '+index);
                        arr.splice(index,1);
                        $('.note.active').remove();
                    } else {                        
                        var cls = Math.max.apply( Math, arr );
                        var index = arr.indexOf(cls);
                        arr.splice(index,1);
                        console.log('.note.'+cls+' '+index);
                        $('.note.'+cls).remove();
                    }
                }   console.log(arr)
            }
        });
    });
    function closeIt(that) {
        var cls = parseInt(that.parent().parent().attr('class').split(' ')[1]);
        var index = arr.indexOf(cls);
        console.log('.note.'+cls+' '+index);
        arr.splice(index,1);
        that.parent().parent().remove();
    }
```